# Moodle Data Request

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

I want to pass the user id (100) to moodle and then get a JSON string about the stored data of the user with the id (100). Is there a way or a web service for this?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to enable Moodle web services, you can follow [this link](https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=319039), then add the "core_user_get_users" function to your external web service, then you can create criteria to search and get user data.

Samples:

```
webservice endpoint: https://<MOODLE_URL>/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=<YOUR_TOKEN>&wsfunction=core_user_get_users&moodlewsrestformat=json&criteria[0][key]=username&criteria[0][value]=<USERNAME>
webservice endpoint: https://<MOODLE_URL>/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=<YOUR_TOKEN>&wsfunction=core_user_get_users&moodlewsrestformat=json&criteria[0][key]=id&criteria[0][value]=<ID>
```

For other response formats change "moodlewsrestformat" in the request.